# Upgraded jquery to 1.4.2. Now project doesn't find jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, visual-studio-2008

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC application which has been using jquery 1.3.2 in VS2008 environment.

I decided to upgrade to 1.4.2 and added the file to my project. Changed the reference in my masterpage header to the new version. But now nothing works, it's like it can't find the jquery library.

What could be wrong?

Comment: So long as the paths are correct it should work. View the HTML source and check the path.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Visual Studio but it might be relevant to say if you renamed the file (e.g. jquery-1.3.2.min.js to jquery-1.4.2.min.js) or you just replaced it (jquery.js).

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that page caching is switched off? Check that the links are being rendered correctly. I would recommend loading the page in Firefox and inspecting with Firebug to see what the script links are and whether the script files are being found.

Answer (score 0):

How about fetching latest JQuery library from google code?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("jquery", "1.4.2"); // version here

  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    // Place init code here instead of $(document).ready()
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an extra } in a separate .js file that caused nothing to load.

Comment: Probably best to delete the question, then, as the answer is entirely specific to your situation and the question isn't actually what's in the title (or indeed, body), so it's not going to be useful to anyone else going forward.

Comment: I would if I could but I am not allowed to delete it.